# SonarQube wrapper gives JVM error on launch

Tags: c++, linux, sonarqube

I am trying to setup SonarQube and test it how it's working Linux. I installed SonarQube developer version. I've tried to run Hello World C++ example made by Sonar (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-build-wrapper-linux).

And when I am launching `/opt/sonarqube-6.7.2/bin/linux-x86-64/wrapper /home/some_user/some_storage/sonar-scanning-examples/sonarqube-scanner-build-wrapper-linux/build.sh`.

I get this error:

```
$ /opt/sonarqube-6.7.2/bin/linux-x86-64/wrapper /home/some_user/some_storage/sonar-scanning-examples/sonarqube-scanner-build-wrapper-linux/build.sh
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 1    | Error: Could not find or load main class Main
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 2    | Error: Could not find or load main class Main
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 3    | Error: Could not find or load main class Main
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 4    | Error: Could not find or load main class Main
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 5    | Error: Could not find or load main class Main
wrapper  | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
wrapper  |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I've also tried to change

```
wrapper.java.command=java
```

to

```
wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java
```

Still it gives error.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like Sonar trying to inspect Java project instead of  C++. Check this https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2014/10/sonarqube-inspections-for-cpp-projects.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Victor Gubin, I understood that CPP wrapper is needed.

> Build Wrapper for Linux can be downloaded from URL http://localhost:9000/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip

More information: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Building+on+Linux